# Iterating and return elements using for loop in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I was trying to access my component by using loop to iterate and call my component. I encountered no syntax error, however I didn't get desired elements out of my loop. Here is a sample code which I tried.

```
    render() {
    return (
      <div>
            {this.genThumbnail([{'src':'../../resources/images/p1.jpg', 'mode':'normal'},
            {'src':'../../resources/images/p2.jpg', 'mode':'normal'},
            {'src':'../../resources/images/p3.jpg', 'mode':'normal'},
            {'src':'../../resources/images/p4.jpg', 'mode':'landscape'},
            {'src':'../../resources/images/p5.jpg', 'mode':'portrait'},
            {'src':'../../resources/images/p6.jpg', 'mode':'landscape'}])}

          </div>
        </div>
)
}

genThumbnail(nails) {
    debugger;
    let src, mode;
    return(
      <div>
        {
          nails.forEach(function (data,index){
              return <ThumbNail imgsrc={data.src} mode={data.mode}/>
          }
        )
        }
      </div>

    )

  }
```

I had to use map() helper method to achieve this. Anyone please clarify the shortcoming as a result of forEach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [`forEach` doesn't return anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). It's meant to be a stand-in for a `for` loop. Even if you return a value in your callback, it won't return anything. `forEach` is (basically) written like this:

```
Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    callback(this[i]); // Notice it doesn't use the return value
  }
};
```

[`map` on the other hand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array using the return value of the callback function to determine what each item in the array is.

So the short answer is: `forEach` doesn't return anything, by design. `map` worked because it **does** return an array, again, by design.

Comment: what about return statement inside the forEach?

Comment: @BilalSaeed Just because you return a value from the callback passed to `forEach` doesn't mean `forEach` will return anything. `forEach` completely ignores the return value of your callback.

Comment: @BilalSaeed when in doubt read the documentation for the method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach. Clearly tells you it returns `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

`Array.forEach` does not return anything. Use `Array.map` instead, which return a new array

```
return(
      <div>
        {
          nails.map(function (data,index){
              return <ThumbNail imgsrc={data.src} mode={data.mode}/>
          }
        )}
      </div>
    )
```

Comment: I already done it using map, I was asking for the explanation why forEach couldn't be used?

Comment: @BilalSaeed There is difference between `map` and `forEach`. `map` function return a new array and each element of that array is the value returned by the callback function passed to it. `forEach` function on the other hand, does not do anything with the value returned by the callback of it and return undefined.